# Mongoose/mongodb how to find and update object/table that is saved in another table

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am saving user in users table and in company table that they belong. Problem is when I update user (by id) i can update user in user table but cant locate/find that user in company table.

I want function to work, when i update user, that it updates in user table and finds him in company table (its bit deeper) and updates him there also. OR there is maybe other easier way to do this.

This is my try:
update route
but i can only find company if id is of creator (owner) of company, not the user i am searching for in company database

```
//Update user by id
router.patch("/updateUser/:id", auth, log, async (req, res) => {
  const _id = req.params.id;
  const updates = Object.keys(req.body);
  const allowedUpdates = ["firstName", "lastName", "role", "email", "password", "confirmed"];
  const isValidOperation = updates.every((update) =>
    allowedUpdates.includes(update)
  );

  if (!isValidOperation) {
    return res.status(400).send({ error: "Invalid updates!" });
  }

  try {
    const user = await User.findById(_id);

    if (!user) {
      return res.status(404).send();
    }

    updates.forEach((update) => (user[update] = req.body[update]));
    await user.save();


    const company = await Company.find({owner: _id});

    const drivers = company[0].users;

    // const driver = await company[0].users.find()

    // updates.forEach((update) => (user[update] = req.body[update]));
    // await company.save();

    res.send(company[0].users);

  } catch (e) {
    res.status(400).send(e);
  }
});
```

And here is company model:

```
const companySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    oib: {
        type: Number
    },
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    address:{
        type: String
    },
    owner: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    users: [
        {
            user: {
                type: Object
            }
    }
    ],
    orders: [
        {
            order: {
                type: Object
            }
    }
]
}, {
    timestamps: true
})
```

and how the company string looks

```
[
    {
        "_id": "6017284c4a0a88712c1d506f",
        "oib": 12345678901,
        "name": "amazon",
        "address": "novska",
        "owner": "60146fbfebc2296410a8cb30",
        "users": [
            {
                "_id": "601728714a0a88712c1d5071",
                "user": {
                    "confirmed": false,
                    "firstLogin": "",
                    "_id": "601728714a0a88712c1d5070",
                    "firstName": "user0",
                    "lastName": "user0",
                    "email": "bvjcunytphhathdayt@upived.online",
                    "password": "user0",
                    "repeatPassword": "user0",
                    "worksFor": "amazon",
                    "tokens": []
                }
            },
            {
                "_id": "60172a260ba15e3e80dbbc75",
                "user": {
                    "confirmed": false,
                    "firstLogin": "",
                    "_id": "60172a260ba15e3e80dbbc74",
                    "firstName": "user1",
                    "lastName": "user1",
                    "email": "bvjcunytphhathfdfyt@upived.online",
                    "password": "user1",
                    "repeatPassword": "user1",
                    "worksFor": "amazon",
                    "tokens": []
                }
            }
        ],
        "orders": [
            {
                "_id": "60174019a9e5dd5028d0f495",
                "order": {
                    "completed": true,
                    "processed": true,
                    "_id": "60174019a9e5dd5028d0f494",
                    "origin": "Novska, Croatia",
                    "destination": "Kutina, Croatia",
                    "company": "amazon",
                    "owner": "60146fbfebc2296410a8cb30"
                }
            }
        ],
        "createdAt": "2021-01-31T21:59:40.520Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-01-31T23:41:13.803Z",
        "__v": 3
    }
]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

from what i understood you are keeping duplicate data, mongodb does not support working with this as you should not do this at all (its really really really bad) , instead of duplicates keep only id. You save space and operations.